# How to make a header in JQM with page number for different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have this form of like 4 pages and some multiple pages and popups inside those 4 page .

What I am trying to do is add a header kind of thing bellow the header which will show the number of the current page with something highlighted or arrow indicating its the current page .

My website is based on JQM so I tried to make a fiddle of what I could do .

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/d9w4Y/3/)

Here is a fiddle related with it . can any one help me out design this .

[**UPDATED Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/d9w4Y/4/)

Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Click</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p> <a data-role="button" href="#foo" class="clicko" id="1">Venta</a>
 <a data-role="button" href="#foo" class="clicko" id="2">Aliquilar</a>
 <a data-role="button" href="#foo" class="clicko" id="3">Busca</a>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
    <div data-role="header"> <a class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" data-direction="reverse" href="#page1">Back to page "one"</a>

            <h1 id="pagem"></h1>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div role="main nopad " class="ui-content" style="padding-left: 0 !important;padding-right: 0 !important;padding-top: 0 !important; ">
        <div class="tracker ui-btn ui-grid-c center" style="border-top-width: 1px; padding: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a class=" center1 ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline">Button</a>
                <div class="line" style="margin-left:62%"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a class=" center1 ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline">Button</a>
                <div class="line" style="margin-right:62%"></div>
                <div class="line" style="margin-left:62%"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c"><a class="center1 ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline">Button</a>
                <div class="line" style="margin-right:62%; top:-21px"></div>
                <div class="line" style="margin-left:62%"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-d"><a class="center1 ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline">Button</a>
                <div class="line" style="margin-right:62%;top:-21px"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>I'm Second in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>
        <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a>

        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.line {
    width: 40%;
    bottom: 22px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
}
.center {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Since the page numbers are fixed, how about using the **pagebeforeshow** event of every page and within the event handler set the title for the particular page?

Comment: @Vijeth you did not get my question I want to change the icons to numbers . Like page number inside the round circle . The heading is not a problem I already implement that in my website . The main problem I am facing is to add page number inside those round circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vikram So I understand that you want the arrow icon to be replaced with page number. Did you try **data-icon** property and specify custom icons?

Other approach would be to override the CSS properties of the button. Add a **customIcon** class to the anchor tag with properties as shown below.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-block-b"><a class=" center1 ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline customIcon">12</a><div class="line" style="margin-right:62%"></div><div class="line" style="margin-left:62%"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.customIcon{
    border-radius: 1em!important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em!important;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1.75em;
    white-space: nowrap!important;
    line-height: 1.8em;
```

}

Now you can access this anchor tag in every **pagebeforeshow** and set the page numbers manually.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks bro it helped a lot now I will have to make the current page glow